# Load another page on the same tab, Maintain the previous url on the address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user is on my homepage `example.com` and he manually select a country from the dropdown menu in my header, the url is `example.com/usa`, I want the `example.com/usa` to open on the same tab without example.com changing to `example.com/usa` in the address bar.

Example of a site that did this is okayafrica.com. When you select like Canada edition [the url for the edition is `okayafrica.com/country/canada`] from the homepage, it will reload on the same tab and show the Canada edition and the address bar will be `okayafrica.com` .

Is there a way I can achieve this with Javascript?

Comment: use folow jquery script: `$("html").load(newurl)`

Comment: Ever heard about routing?

Comment: @diavolic can you help with a detailed code answer. I know nothing about javascript. :(

Comment: @abishek no, I've not heard of it before. Kindly tell me.

Comment: @abhishekkhandait routing has nothing to do with this

Comment: all you need is jQuery load function or ajax

Comment: Can you please explain with a detailed code ? I don't know javascript or jquery. :(

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming you are using jQuery, below code should suffice.**

```
$("button").click(function(){// any event you can bind on which you want to load new page.
    $("html").load("usa", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
        if(statusTxt == "success")
            alert("External content loaded successfully!");
        if(statusTxt == "error")
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });
});
```

**Below is full sample html explaining above code.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("html").load("usa", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
            if(statusTxt == "success")
                alert("External content loaded successfully!");
            if(statusTxt == "error")
                alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain maybe with html code too. Now, the 'button' is the class or id? I guess the demo_test.xt is the url of the page the needs to be loaded next?

Comment: updated my code,   $("html").load("url" , url is the relative url with respect to current page.  Yes  url is the url of next page.

Comment: When I insert like 'quick.html' in the load() it worked just that it didn't display the page properly as it was supposed to when you load quick.html in the address bar. But when I input 'example.com' in the load() function, it pop out error 0. It didn't load the url. I will be dealing with url not like a page name. Is there a fix for this? :)

Comment: I did this  $("html").load("https://example.com", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){ still error.. or I should change 'html' to http?

Comment: How about doing some reading and learning: http://api.jquery.com/load/  (hint: the examples don't have semicolon after the url, the `html` is the element where loaded content is inserted, the "url" you load must be same domain or it fails due to cross-site-scripting. Urls can be relative (`usa`), root-relative (`/usa`) or absolute (`http://example.com/usa`) Look it up!)

Comment: I've done that. yet to figure out why it's not working for me.

Comment: Make sure that all the pages should be on same domain, As ajax create problems when you try to access cross domain pages

Comment: I did. they are on the same domain. This is driving me crazy! Don't know maybe wordpress is blocking the page or something.

Comment: provide jsfiddle for ur application please

Comment: AH wordpress!!  Open your browser dev tools (F12) then check the errors on console tab. Then replace each `$` in your code with `jQuery` and reload page. Does that solve it?